# Multithreading vs Parallel Processing in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Ok, so as my first foray into python programming (I code in other languages, just never python) and I decided to make a "bot" to play the popular game Friday Night Funkin. I believe the other parts of my code work except for the part that keeps track of each arrow.

I am trying to run a single generic method that I wrote to account for one of the 4 arrows

```
def generic_arrow_logic(arrType, thread):
    global color_dictionary, key_dictionary
    print("Thread {0} running...".format(thread))
    while (True):
        wholeImage = screenGrab("curr")
        currArr = cutImage(wholeImage, arrType, "not")
        currArr.save(arrowArrayCurr)

        currArr_rgb = currArr.convert("RGB")
        if(currArr_rgb.getpixel((currArr.width/2, currArr.height/2)) == color_dictionary[arrType]):
            # pyautogui.press(key_dictionary[arrType])
            keyboard.write(key_dictionary[arrType],delay=0)
            print("Thread:{0} - {1}, Detected...".format(str(thread), str(arrType).upper()))
```

I included the print statements on the bottom to check whether or not its working.

My 2 attempts at this so far have been using the multiprocessing module and the Threading module as follows:

```
    pool = Pool(processes = 4)
    for dir in direction_array:
        pool.apply_async(generic_arrow_logic, args=(dir,direction_array.index(dir)))
        print("starting thread " + str(direction_array.index(dir)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

and Threading:

```
    for dir in direction_array:
        threading.Thread(target=generic_arrow_logic(dir, direction_array.index(dir))).start()
```

For reference, color_dictionary, direction_array and key_dictionary are here:

```
color_dictionary = {"right":right, "left":left_arrow_color, "up":up_arrow_color, "down":down_arrow_color, "default":default_arrow_color}

direction_array = ["right", "left", "up", "down"]

key_dictionary = {"right":rightKey, "left":leftKey, "up":upKey, "down":downKey}
```

Edit: I realize people don't really know what I'm asking. My question is, "How am I supposed to run any given method concurrently?". Currently, I get one of two different outputs when I run my program.
When I run the multiprocessing one, it fails to spawn the processes and ends up looping a completely different part of the program like below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jalen Morgan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Jalen Morgan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Jalen Morgan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Jalen Morgan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Jalen Morgan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, 
in run_path
```

and when I run the threading one, only one thread starts

```
---------Welcome to my FNF Bot--------
-----------Select an Option-----------
Region: ((1758, 316),(1459, 244))     
1.) Select region
2.) Start Bot
3.) Exit

Enter an option: 2
Thread 0 running...
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: edited to reflect actual question